# Nested Async and Await in Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm using Xamarin Forms with Xamarin Studio on a Mac Mini, and I'm having an async/await issue I was hoping someone could help with.  I have a button click event defined as:

```
void LoginButton_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Do some stuff
  this.HandleSignInCompleted(..);
}
```

This then calls a method to do some user profile initialization, which it needs to contact the server:

```
async void HandleSignInCompleted(..)
{
  var profile = await _profileService.GetAsync ().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This waits indefinitely, whether `ConfigureAwait` is present or not.  The user profile service simple does the following right now (just returns myself for testing):

```
    public async Task<UserProfile> GetAsync()
    {
        //wrapper around app properties
        var accessToken = (string)_appProperties.Get ("token"); 

        //Tried with ConfigureAwait and without
        await Task.Delay (100);

        //TODO:replace with facebook load
        return new UserProfile (..);
    }
```

With `ConfigureAwait(false)`, `Task.Delay` chokes.  Without it, it works, but the debugger crashed.  What's going on and how can I resolve this issue so that the AJAX request (when I replace it in the user profile service in the future) will work?

Comment: Slightly unrelated: You are using a void in an async method(Note the exception for event handlers). Perhaps change it to Task as per the guideline: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sync-over-async is an antipattern; you're at the mercy not only of your own code (must use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere), but also at the mercy of any libraries you call. In particular, I've run into a similar issue on Xamarin in the past regarding `Task.Delay`. And before you try switching it out for a real network call, `HttpClient` has the same problem on some mobile platforms (either iOS or Android, don't remember ATM). Not sure if Facebook would have a similar bug or not.

So, in summary, you really just can't do that. Instead, embrace `async` all the way:

```
async Task HandleSignInCompletedAsync(..)
{
  var profile = await _profileService.GetAsync ().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

async void LoginButton_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Do some stuff
  await this.HandleSignInCompletedAsync(..);
}
```

Disable controls if you have to, but don't block. A nice side effect of this approach is that your app is always more responsive.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.  Is there a rationale when to use configureawait and when not to?  It doesn't seem like there's a lot of documentation on it, just that it's a trick to get around these sorts of problems?

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` is an optimization that can be applied any time the `async` method does not need to return to its context.